# Error al pasar parametros por GET

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de pasar un par de parámetros de un script jquery a un script de php.

Este es el código que tengo:

```
<?php
include('index.php');
$fecha =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conex,$_GET['fecha']);
$placa =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conex,$_GET['placa']);
echo $fecha. " " . $placa;
mysqli_query($conex, "SELECT fecha, asistencia.idvehuser FROM asistencia, vehiculouser WHERE asistencia     .idvehuser = vehiculouser.idvehuser AND vehiculouser.placa = '".$placa."' AND asistencia                     .fecha = '".$fecha."'");
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conex)){
        $html = true;
    } else {
        $html = false;
}
echo $html; ?>
```

Se supone que debería mostrarme las dos variables que pasó por GET, pero solo me la `$placa`, los valores que estoy pasando son lo siguientes:

- 01/01/2020
- abc123

la verdad no se que pasa, si alguien puede ver mi error lo agradecería.

Comment: Por favor muestra el código que usas para mandar los datos desde el cliente (HTML-JS-jQuery).

Comment: pon el código jquery

Comment: Puede colocar el query que estas pasando por el metodo GET.